# F# list to C# IEnumerable: most efficient method?

Tags: c#, .net, list, f#, seq

I'm currently working on an F# library with GUI written in C# and I would like to ask what is the best or correct way to pass an F# (generic) list to a C# code (generic IEnumerable).

I've found three ways so far:

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5;] |> List.toSeq

[1; 2; 3; 4; 5;] |> Seq.ofList 

[1; 2; 3; 4; 5;] :> seq<int>
```

Is there any practical difference between these three methods, please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look in the F# library source code, you'll find out that they are all the same:

- `Seq.ofList` just calls `List.ofSeq` as you can see [here in the "list.fs" file](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/25890f73b7491719a77c2f0014ad9960fca3283e/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L574)
- `List.toSeq` is implemented using `s :> seq<_>` as you can see [here in the "seq.fs" file](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/37a100b7caafde0f4df5a1924c9f65f4a18277a8/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1217)

In terms of readability, I would probably use `Seq.ofList` or `List.toSeq`, especially if the code is a part of a larger F# pipeline, because then it makes the code a bit nicer:

```
someInput
|> List.map (fun x -> whatever) 
|> List.toSeq
```

Comment: To expand a bit on Tomas's excellent answer: my general recommendation on whether to use `Seq.ofList` or `List.toSeq` would be to ask yourself "What is my code using?" If (as in this example) you have a list and you want to produce a seq/IEnumerable for other code to consume, then use `List.toSeq`. If you have received a list and you want to get a seq for your own code to consume, use `Seq.ofList`. In other words, pick the function that most matches the "direction" of data flow in this particular part of your code.

Comment: If you nuget `FSharp.Core.Fluent` you will be able to dot into the list like: `[1;2;3].toSeq()`.